# Send HTML formatted mail from Pentaho

Tags: html, email, pentaho, pdi, spoon

I need to loop through a database table and send a html formatted mail.

Nothing complex, a text value followed by a hyperlink.
[image]

I tried with xml and xsl transformation but couldn't get desired results.

ALso, advise on whether its better to construct hyperlink in PostGressql or is it okay from Pentaho

I tried with a Table Input and a Javascript step. Thing is it outputs for each row. i need to combine and concatenate each row output to form  result HTML

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pentaho: get your data with a `table input`, make the html (for example with a `java script`), get the mail parameters (addresse, attachement, etc,...) from a `grid` or a `constant` step, and give the whole to the `mail` step.

[image]

With the javascript you built a -tag by row named `html`, but you need only one message. So you group them with a `Group by` step (no `Group field`, subject=`html`, type=`Concatenate strings separated by`, value=empty). You can then drop it in the `Mail` step.

But the `Mail` step needs some more information (recipient, sender, subject, server, port,...). You can put them in the flow with a `Constant` step.

In view of your use-case, it may surprise you that you have to put this data in the flow rather than to feed a box in the `Mail` step. This is because this step is designed to send a mail personalized for each recipient.

And now that you know how to do it, refrain from sending 100000 mails to every one you can.

Comment: Also, please note that in Pentaho javascript you are not necessarily need to put html code into string literals, since you may use XML literals as specified in e4x(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X): something like `var output = <html><head/><body>EDW - <a href="{edw_link}">{edw_link_text}</a></body></html>`. You might be required to convert xml to string with `output.toXMLString()` method (not sure about, been awhile since I've worked with Pentaho). In braces you can use variable or column names - they will be substituted with their values.

Comment: Thanks. How do you loop through records using javascript. Assuming i have 2 columns. 
Column1                                         Column2
Enterprise Data Warehouse (EDW) 3610985
Enterprise IT Compliance & Controls Group (Equity Edge Online) 3610983

Comment: Well, the javascript step does not re-initialize the variables that were not declared with a `var` keyword. You can therefore "accumulate" the values of the `html_Column2` into `html_Column1`. If you need to initialize `html_Column`, right-click on the tab (named Script 1), add a new tab, then right-click on the new tab (named Item 0), define it as the StartScript, and put `var html_Column1 = "start value"` there.

Comment: sorry, 'am not able to follow. 
my intention is to fetch data from each row and append it to a global variable, so that i can sendd the global variable to mail as html content.

Comment: I declared an environment variable, appended data from each row and finally sent the variable to Mail step as html content. It works. Not sure approach is right but it works